# Ajustar texto en pantalla desarrollo netbeans

Tags: netbeans

pongo comentarios largos en una sola linea en netbeans, y sale de la pantalla lo que hace que tenga que usar la barra de desplazamiento horizontal
Hay una combinación de teclas para que se ajuste a la pantalla de desarrollo?
que le ponga salto de lineas de manera automatica

Comment: Hola Victor, bienvenido, siguiendo la ruta: **`tools/options/ ->Editor/Formatting`** elegis en el segundo selector **`comments`**, y vas a encontrar muchas opciones para formatear los comentarios, una vez que setees lo que te apetece, das `apply` y en tu clase vas a **`Source/Format`**, y listo. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora lo pruebo
pensé que había alguna combinación de teclas como alt + shit + f para indentar, que me acomodaba el texto en la pantalla

Comment: Exactamente esa es la combinación, pero antes tienes que indicarle al ide, que quieres que haga.